# I'm getting "Topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms" message on some computers

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Here's my program

```
package kafkaConsumer;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.*;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class KafkaConsumerExample {
    private final static String INTOPIC = "my-intopic";
    private final static String OUTTOPIC = "my-outtopic";
    private final static String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "192.168.10.10:9092";

    private static Producer<Long, String> createProducer(String bootstrapServers) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaProducerExample");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        return new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    }

    private static Consumer<Long, String> createConsumer(String intopic, String bootstrapServers) {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaConsumerExample");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "1");
        // Create the consumer using props.
        final Consumer<Long, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        // Subscribe to the topic.
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(intopic));
        return consumer;
    }

    static boolean run(
            Consumer<Long, String> consumer, Producer<Long, String> producer,
            String inTopic, String outTopic) throws InterruptedException {

        String valueToSend;
        long keyToUse;

        if (consumer == null) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter key> ");
            keyToUse = sc.nextLong();
            valueToSend = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter value> ");
            valueToSend = sc.nextLine();
        } else {
            Duration delta = Duration.ofSeconds(1);
            ConsumerRecords<Long, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(delta);
            while (consumerRecords.count() == 0) {
                consumerRecords = consumer.poll(delta);
            }
            ConsumerRecord<Long, String> record = consumerRecords.iterator().next();
            keyToUse = record.key();
            valueToSend = record.value();
            if (producer != null)
                System.out.println("Got key = " + keyToUse + " and value = " + valueToSend);
        }

        if (producer == null) {
            System.out.println("key = " + keyToUse + " and value = " + valueToSend);
        } else {
            try {
                System.out.println("Creating ProducerRecord");
                final ProducerRecord<Long, String> record =
                        new ProducerRecord<>(outTopic, keyToUse, valueToSend);
                System.out.println("Calling producer.send");
                Future<RecordMetadata> sent = producer.send(record);
                System.out.println("Calling sent.get");
                RecordMetadata metadata = sent.get();
                System.out.println("Calling flush");
                producer.flush();
                System.out.println("After flush");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception sending message: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return !valueToSend.equals("STOP");
    }

    public static void usage() {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.java.command"));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Usage parameters: [--intopic name] [--outtopic name] [--bootstrap-servers servers]");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        String inTopic = INTOPIC;
        String outTopic = OUTTOPIC;
        String bootstrapServers = BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS;

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
            if (args[i].equals("--intopic")) {
                if (i == args.length - 1) {
                    usage();
                }
                inTopic = args[++i];
            } else if (args[i].equals("--outtopic")) {
                if (i == args.length - 1) {
                    usage();
                }
                outTopic = args[++i];
            } else if (args[i].equals("--bootstrap-servers")) {
                if (i == args.length - 1) {
                    usage();
                }
                bootstrapServers = args[++i];
            } else {
                usage();
            }
        }

        final Consumer<Long, String> consumer;
        if (inTopic.equals("stdin")) {
            consumer = null;
        } else {
            consumer = createConsumer(inTopic, bootstrapServers);
        }
        final Producer<Long, String> producer;
        if (outTopic.equals("stdout")) {
            producer = null;
        } else {
            producer = createProducer(bootstrapServers);
        }

        while (true) {
            if (!run(consumer, producer, inTopic, outTopic)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (consumer != null)
            consumer.close();
        if (producer != null)
            producer.close();
    }
}
```

I run it on Windows and Linux. On some computers it runs fine, but on other computers, specifically a Linux machine which is not the kafka machine, it consistently gives me this error:

```
Exception sending message: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic outtopic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

This happens, of course, when trying to send a message in the `run()` function, specifically in the sentence `RecordMetadata metadata = sent.get()`.

This kafka installation allows creation of new topics automatically. In fact, if I enter a new name in the --outtopic parameter, even when sending the message fails, the topic is created.

Any clues why? What am I missing in the configuration?

Thank you

Shimon

Comment: No, it's not in a docker container. It's a set of computers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
192.168.10.10:9092
```

This seems to be an internal IP. Check if the clients where you cannot access are within its network range i.e. whether they can access this IP.

Try doing a telnet from your client machine..

```
telnet 192.168.10.10 9092
```

If you are not able to `telnet` then give the IP which can be accessed by your clients and ensure the same in the `advertised.listeners` also.

Also check your `advertised.listeners` config. When we connect to a url given in the `bootstrap.servers` that typically should par with those in the `advertised.listeners` configuration.

Topic metadata not present means that your client is unable to fetch any information about the given topic i.e. it cannot get metadata through the given `bootstrap.servers` property.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the IP address before posting this. But it is in fact an internal IP address that I'm using. Telnet works from the computer to the kafka host.
Also, it's not that the communication fails. As I said, if I use a new topic, the topic gets created; it's just the sending of the message that fails with this message.

Comment: @Shimon Did you check your `advertised.listeners` config? The IP you specify in that config should be accessible from your client machine and should also point to the IP of the machine where Kafka is running

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to set `advertised.listeners`. Where should I define it on the client machine?

Comment: @Shimon It is a broker config. You need to edit the `server.properties` file which you give while starting the kafka broker

Comment: Added `advertised.listeners` to `server.properties` and restarted kafka service. Still not working. Note that when I run the same program from my laptop (Windows) it does run successfully (and it also ran successfully without the `advertised.listeners` configuration).

Comment: And I made one mistake above. When I run the program, the topic does *not* get created as I thought before.

Comment: @Shimon how did you add it? it is *typically* `PLAINTEXT://<IP>:<PORT>`. This `IP:Port` is what you need to give in the `bootstrap.servers`

Comment: Thank you very much @JavaTechnical. I found that I needed both `advertised.listeners` config and also, shame on me, to stop the firewalld daemon:). I will configure the firewall later, but for now the `advertised.listeners` did the trick!. Thanks from the bottom of my heart.